# Email confirmation - strange behavior

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity, email-confirmation, asp.net-core-configuration

Does anyone have an idea why this is happening to me?

In this case, 'result' is **'Success'**:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> TestConfirmInSameRequest(string userId)
{
    var user = await this._userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
    var code = await this._userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
    var result = await this._userManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(user, code); 

    var newLocation = ...
    return Redirect(newLocation);
}
```

And in this case, 'result' always is **'InvalidToken'** (even when I manually copy the original code and test with it)

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ConfirmEmail(string userId, string code)
{
    var user = await this._userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
    var result = await this._userManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(user, code); 

    var newLocation = ...;
    return Redirect(newLocation);
}

protected async Task SendConfirmationEmail(string userId, bool originMobile)
{
    var user = await this._userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
    var code = await this._userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);

    var encodedCode = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(code);
    var callbackUrl = $"https://.../api/account/confirmemail?userId={userId}&code={encodedCode}";

    await this._userService.SendConfirmationEmailAsync(userId, callbackUrl);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When sending (*SendConfirmationEmail*) the e-mail you `urlencode` the token, but in ConfirmEmail you are not `decoding` the token.

Encoding it just makes sure it can be used in a URL and no breaking characters are in the URL. However, *the token you should validate is not the encoded one*, its still the token you got before encoding. In other words; you need to decode the token again so its back to the way it was when it got generated.

Comment: The 'code' comes as already decoded. I have also tried decoding it using HttpUtility.UrlDecode(code). - Same result except that in this case when I compare the original generated code and the decoded, they look different as the decoded one is missing '+' symbols that were present before decoding and in the original one.

Comment: Also as I've mentioned in the question, I tried copying the 'code' right after it was generated, and then pasting it in the 'ConfirmEmail' method directly, which also results in 'InvalidToken'.